# Move Post Title above Post Date Wordpress Visual Composer

Tags: wordpress, visual-composer

Is there any way to move the title above the date and change the date settings to "Date" instead of "Posted 4 days ago"?

I'm using Albertino theme with visual Composer

Comment: by using customization you can move date above title and date both. create child theme of Albertino theme and as per your requirement you can change the page  template  "page-template-blog"

Answer (score 0):

**Solved**

by using the excerpt template and changing Show post date after to '1' on date settings on Visual Composer Global Options